# How can I enlarge and adapt image on a ImageView with Picasso lib

Tags: android, picasso

I wanna ask you if exist in Android Library "Picasso" from square: "http://square.github.io/picasso/" any image function center and enlarge to adapt my image to all devices. For example, this is my app on my Galaxy note 2:

[image]

Is there any properties or any way to zoom into the image and adapt to the frame with Picasso?

Image properties:

```
ImageView image;

String currentUrl="http://mw2.google.com/mw-panoramio/photos/medium/48958465.jpg";

image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.place_image);
Picasso.with(v.getContext())
.load(currentUrl)
.error(R.drawable.benitomussolinimarker)
.into(image);

Picasso.with(this)
.load(currentUrl)
.into(target);

private Target target = new Target()
{
    @Override
     public void onBitmapLoaded(final Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) 
    {
     new Thread(new Runnable() 
     {
         @Override
         public void run() 
         {           

             File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() +"/actress_wallpaper.jpg");
             try 
             {
                 file.createNewFile();
                 FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                 bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 75, ostream);
                 ostream.close();
             } 
             catch (Exception e) 
             {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }

         } //public void run
     }).start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
};
```

ImageView XML:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/place_image"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:background="#222222"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: what scale type did you set for the imageview?

Comment: @blackbelt I edit my question with the properties I set and xml of the imageview :)

Comment: @blackbelt I need a resize property that maintains the image proportions..example, if I load a super bigger image...5000 x 3000 he should resize the image but respecting proporions of the image...I cannot use .fit()

Comment: I am not experienced with picasso, but to scale the bitmap you can use the `inSampleSize` property of `BitmapFactory.Options`

Comment: @blackbelt I solved my problems, now I will update the answer, thank you so much !

Answer (score 1):

You can resize the image according to your device height and width.

```
DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
        int height = (displaymetrics.heightPixels * 40) / 100;
        int width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;

        ImageView qImage = new ImageView(this);
        Picasso.with(this)
                .load(ServerURL.BASE_URL + "image_url")
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_rectangle_logo)
                .error(R.drawable.ic_rectangle_logo).resize(width, height)
                .into(qImage);
```

Comment: @AshvinSAshok I solved, now I will edit with solution :)

Comment: @AshvinSAshok sorry I solved, but not with your solution. But your solution is correct too, anyway, my solution is more practical.

Answer (score 1):

I solved using .fit().centerCrop() here my code:

```
String currentUrl="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/50/Casa_Natale_Benito_Mussolini_(1).jpg";
image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.place_image);

Picasso.with(v.getContext())
.load(currentUrl)
.error(R.drawable.marker)  
.fit().centerCrop() // allarga l'immagine
.into(image);
```

and this is my new screen ^^

[image]